# cannot set checked of undefined (saving checkboxs w/ localStorage)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, local-storage

I am saving my checkbox states with localStorage, then re-rendering them later (when button is clicked) the below seems to be working for the most part; except it's erroring in my load function with `'cannot set checked of undefined'`.

*Note my checkboxes don't come from standard HTML mark-up they are dynamically invoked with javascript - perhaps there's a better way then using `input.checked`?*

```
function checkSaver() { 
  user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(user));

  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  user.userAchkData = [];

  inputs.forEach(function(input){
    user.userAchkData.push({ id: input.id, checked: input.checked });
  });

  localStorage.setItem(username, JSON.stringify(user));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(user));

}
```

---

```
function load_() { 
  // get saved latest checkbox states, recheck
  user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(user));
  var inputs = user.userAchkData;

  inputs.forEach(function(input){ 
    document.getElementById(input.id).checked = input.checked; // erroring here, cannot set checked of undefined
  });
```

---

*Full error:* (although it is actually checking the boxes?) Derives from after the = sign above. Any pointers?

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null
    at eval (eventHandlers.js:339)
    at Array.forEach ()
    at load_ (eventHandlers.js:338)**

Comment: If `document.getElementById(input.id)` returns `null` then your input is probably not in the document.

Comment: How are you invoking the checkboxes dynamically?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier But it's actually working?

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that you are not checking that the variable is correctly set.

try with this:

```
function load_() { 
  // get saved latest checkbox states, recheck
  // but first lets define a default value.
  const defaultData = { userAchkData: [] };
  const localStorageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(user));
  let user = localStorageData || defaultData;
  let inputs = user.userAchkData;

  inputs.forEach(function(input){ 
    document.getElementById(input.id).checked = input.checked; // erroring here, cannot set checked of undefined
  });
```

same applies for the `save` function.

```
function checkSaver() { 
  const defaultData = { userAchkData: [] };
  const localStorageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(user));
  let user = localStorageData || defaultData;

  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  user.userAchkData = [];

  inputs.forEach(function(input){
    user.userAchkData.push({ id: input.id, checked: input.checked });
  });

  localStorage.setItem(username, JSON.stringify(user));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(user));

}
```

Comment: So, This seems to loose my other data properties under 'user' when implemented

Comment: I like the logic of this; but the error still persists and it also wipes out my other saved properties in object local storage 'user'

Comment: @CaptainRon have you tried with loggin the `input` inside the `for-each` to see if the data is correct?

Comment: Thanks, I have found the problem; a few of my inputs in the long list of many, are found without IDs.